# RESTEasy, how to generate dynamic APIs based on XML or something programmatically

Tags: rest, jboss, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

Suppose I have and XML file, which defines some core services.

I want to generate REST API using Rest Easy dynamically based on those services for post and get functionalities.

```
    <services>
       <service>
         <type>BankBalance</type>
         <field1>account_no</field1>
         <field2>pin</field2>
       <service>
       <service>
         <type>Deposit</type>
         <field1>account_no</field1>
         <field2>pin</field2>
         <field3>amount</field3>
       <service>
    </services>
```

I want to auto generate the REST APIs, from this using RESTEasy to provide paths like

http://exampleserver/rest/api/services/bankbalance/{account_no}/{pin}
http://exampleserver/rest/api/services/deposit/{account_no}/{pin}/amount

Comment: If you are open to alternatives to xml you can take a look at [RAML](http://raml.org/) (RESTful API Modeling Language) and the [raml-for-jax-rs maven plugin](https://github.com/mulesoft/raml-for-jax-rs/blob/master/maven-plugin.md).

Comment: Sorry lefloh, thats not my requirement. I have few services already created based on XMLs and vice versa. No scope of alternatives.